# pass props to dynamic child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a multiple step form. I have created the form where in each step, corresponding form is rendered dynamically. But I have no idea on how should I pass props to those component so that when returning back, the state gets preserved. I have created a sandbox of it in codesandbox and here it is

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xzm2mxol2

The rendering of form is done the following way

```
{this.props.steps[this.state.componentState].component}
```

If the component is rendered as below which is static way, the code would be something like this but I want the dynamic way

```
if(this.state.componentState === 1) {
 <Form1 props={props} />
}
```

The code is

```
import React from 'react';
import './fullscreenForm.css';

class MultipleForm extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.hidden = {
      display: "none"
    };
    this.state = {
      email: 'steve@apple.com',
      fname: 'Steve',
      lname: 'Jobs',
      open: true,
      step: 1,
      showPreviousBtn: false,
      showNextBtn: true,
      componentState: 0,
      navState: this.getNavStates(0, this.props.steps.length)
    };
  }

  getNavStates(indx, length) {
    let styles = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (i < indx) {
        styles.push("done");
      } else if (i === indx) {
        styles.push("doing");
      } else {
        styles.push("todo");
      }
    }
    return { current: indx, styles: styles };
  }

  checkNavState(currentStep) {
    if (currentStep > 0 && currentStep < this.props.steps.length) {
      this.setState({
        showPreviousBtn: true,
        showNextBtn: true
      });
    } else if (currentStep === 0) {
      this.setState({
        showPreviousBtn: false,
        showNextBtn: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showPreviousBtn: true,
        showNextBtn: false
      });
    }
  }

  setNavState(next) {
    this.setState({
      navState: this.getNavStates(next, this.props.steps.length)
    });
    if (next < this.props.steps.length) {
      this.setState({ componentState: next });
    }
    this.checkNavState(next);
  }

  next = () => {
    this.setNavState(this.state.componentState + 1);
  };

  previous = () => {
    if (this.state.componentState > 0) {
      this.setNavState(this.state.componentState - 1);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent-container">
        <div className="form-block">
        {this.props.steps[this.state.componentState].component}
        </div>
        <div 
          className="actions" 
          style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}
          >
          <button
            style={this.state.showPreviousBtn ? {} : this.hidden}
            className="btn-prev"
            onClick={this.previous}
          >
            Back
          </button>

          <button
            style={this.state.showNextBtn ? {} : this.hidden}
            className="btn-next"
            onClick={this.next}
          >
            Continue
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MultipleForm;
```

I wanted it in best practice way.

Comment: I think you can use redux for this. With redux all the properties can be stored globally and it will be accessible from anywhere in SPA site.

Comment: @SergeyGultyaev Thanks for your reply. can you help me to make it work in the react way? I want to know how can i pass props such way.

Comment: I feel like MultipleForm should be holding the steps and all of the Form components since it's holding the email state and w/e. You could then pass down a function which calls a `setState` from the MultipleForm

Comment: For a multipage form you should have one parent container which holds the state of the form and passes props to its children. For more complex applications you can use state management such as redux, but it is not necessary here.

Comment: @A.Lau Can you show me a sample by editing in the codesandbox?

Comment: I honestly don't know how your react works, since it's giving me errors that I never get in my react version. But here's a general idea you can work with. https://codesandbox.io/s/pk148kjjm7 Look mainly at `MultipleForms` and `Form1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the values of your form for all the step inputs. Now since on every step you are changing the form component, so you cannot put those values in corresponding form component. Therefore you have to put those values in the parent container (i.e. `MultipleForm`). Now as you are maintaining a state of values of your child component in parent container, therefore you will have to put some kind of mechanism so that whenever there is any change in input in child component, it should update the corresponding state in parent container. For that you can pass a change handler function to you child component. So your form component should look something like this

```
<div className="fullscreen-form">
        <div className="custom-field">
          <label className="custom-label fs-anim-upper" for="email">
            What's your email address?
          </label>
          <input
            className="fs-anim-lower"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            onChange={this.props.handleChange} // Whenver the input changes then call the parent container's handleChange function so that it can update it's state accordingly
            value={this.props.value} // Updated value passed from parent container
            placeholder="steve@apple.com"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

And you will render your form something like this

```
<Form1 handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />
```

Here's a working solution of your code:: [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2p5r5l7r7)

Comment: This one is working seamlessly. Thanks for your help